# Get a list of objects at each nested level

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
{
    "John Doe": {
        "Age": 18,
        "Gender": "M"
    },
    "Jane Doe": {
        "Age": 16,
        "Gender": "F"
    },
    "Steve Appleseed":{
        "Age": 21,
        "Gender": "M"
    }
}
```

Using JavaScript, how do I get an array

```
var names = ["John Doe", "Jane Doe", "Steve Appleseed"];
```

If it helps, I'm using Firebase with a JavaScript and jQuery PWA, and I need a list of all the names of objects at a nesting particular level.

Comment: So then later, to get John's age, I would use: json[names[0]]["Age"]; json being the name of the root object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly note that this has nothing to do with JSON. What you have is an object. Therefore `Object.keys` will do what you require:

```js
var obj = {
  "John Doe": {
    "Age": 18,
    "Gender": "M"
  },
  "Jane Doe": {
    "Age": 16,
    "Gender": "F"
  },
  "Steve Appleseed": {
    "Age": 21,
    "Gender": "M"
  }
}

var keys = Object.keys(obj);
console.log(keys);

console.log(obj[keys[0]]["Age"]); // John Doe's age
```

Comment: You're missing a semicolon on the `obj` initialization. Should be `var obj = {...};`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Object.keys(obj)`

For more detail, you can see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

```js
var obj = {
    "John Doe": {
        "Age": 18,
        "Gender": "M"
    },
    "Jane Doe": {
        "Age": 16,
        "Gender": "F"
    },
    "Steve Appleseed":{
        "Age": 21,
        "Gender": "M"
    }
};

var result = Object.keys(obj);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var obj = {
    "John Doe": {
        "Age": 18,
        "Gender": "M"
    },
    "Jane Doe": {
        "Age": 16,
        "Gender": "F"
    },
    "Steve Appleseed":{
        "Age": 21,
        "Gender": "M"
    }
}

    console.log(Object.keys(obj))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `object.keys();`
for more information you can check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

```js
t = {
    "John Doe": {
        "Age": 18,
        "Gender": "M"
    },
    "Jane Doe": {
        "Age": 16,
        "Gender": "F"
    },
    "Steve Appleseed":{
        "Age": 21,
        "Gender": "M"
    }
}

Object.keys(t);
```